# JAXB Binding to change xs:date to xs:dateTime?

Tags: xml, soap, jaxb

I have to access a flawed web service where some fields in the WSDL have the type xs:date but I have to fill them as xs:dateTime.

Is it possible to use a JAXB Bindings file to change the type of a field in a WSDL?

A snippet of the WSDL:

```
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="startTime" type="xs:date" />
          <xs:element name="stopTime" type="xs:date" />
        </xs:sequence>
```

Comment: XJC binds both `xs:date` and `xs:dateTime` to `java.util.Date` anyway, so the generated code is no different.

Comment: But I'm missing time portion in my request, when the type is xs:date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @XmlSchemaType annotation to configure the XML representation:

```
@XmlElement(name = "date-of-birth")
@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateOfBirth;
```

For more information see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/01/jaxb-and-datetime-properties.html

Comment: I'm using CXF which uses JAXB to generate Java stubs to access the web service. The type of the generated fields is XMLGregorianCalendar, I can live with that but when I send the request the SOAP fields should be filled with "2011-03-29T15:00:00.000+02:00" instead of "2011-03-29+02:00" for example.

Comment: @peter - Can you modify your model classes with the @XmlSchemaType annotation, or do you need to use what is generated?

Comment: Hi, I need to use the generated sources. It's more of theoretical interest for me because the provider of the WSDL will fix the bug in their next release and the project I work for is still in the development phase. I already use a JAX-WS bindings file to fix problems with the WSDL when an Element has the same name like an Attribute in a xs:sequence. So the question is more JAX-WS related than with JAXB I mixed this up.

Comment: @peter did you ever figure out how to fix this without changing the wsdl?